# How can I cancel the ongoing navigation?

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I'm trying to prevent navigating to most of my sites' pages when user is not yet logged in.
So this is the code I started to write to solve that issue:

```
router.on("router:navigation:processing", function (instruction, usedRouter) {

    if (!userLoggedIn && instruction.config.moduleId !== "login") {
        router.navigate('login'); //no better way???
    }
}
```

I would like to find a better alternative to the "router.navigate()"... Didn't find any instruction.cancelNavigation() or anything like that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional routing in Durandal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119544/conditional-routing-in-durandal)

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this seems to be the apropriate way to go, even if I'm experiencing some other problems using that. 
Seems that using the default route ("") breaks the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, linked to [Conditional routing in Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119544/conditional-routing-in-durandal)  (see [how to code it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17090558/3193607) and the [official doc](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/Router/method/guardRoute) about it)

Thanks @Matthew !